# delete a dot element from a list a sentences

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of sentence and i have some element of this list which contains only "." (the element : ".")

Here the list :

```
['SECURITY TERMS.', 'This Exhibit C to between ', '.']
```

I would like to remove all the dot elements from the list .

My expected result is :

```
['SECURITY TERMS.', 'This Exhibit C to between ']
```

For this I try like this :

```
def remove_tabulation_item(sent_text):
    x='.'
    for i in range(len(sent_text) - 1, -1, -1):
        if x in sent_text[i]:
            del sent_text[i]
    return sent_text
```

But the problem whith this code is that is delete all the element which cotains not only "."

Can you help me please?

Comment: `if x in sent_text[i]` checks to see if `x` is _ANYWHERE_ in `sent_text[i]`. What you want is `if x == sent_text[i]`

Answer (score -1):

I would do it following way:

```
sentence = ['SECURITY TERMS.', 'This Exhibit C to between ', '.']
nodots = [i for i in sentence if i!='.']
print(nodots) # prints ['SECURITY TERMS.', 'This Exhibit C to between ']
```